# overload resolution in templates

Tags: c++, templates

Any one Explain this with an example

```
  "Involving conversions on a function argumentsinvolved in template
   parameter deduction."
```

EXamples like this:

```
 template<class T> struct B { /* ... */ };
 template<class T> struct D : public B<T> { /* ... */ };
 template<class T> void f(B<T>&);
 void g(B<int>& bi, D<int>& di)
   {
    f(bi);
    f(di);
   }
```

Please give me some more examples

EDIT: It is a point /  statement from ISO C++ Standard 14.8.3/5th :Overload resolution

Comment: Can you please post the whole sentence, instead of only a part of it? It’s not clear what your question is.

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such. We will not solve your homework for you, but we will provide you with hints that help you *understand*.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph :It is a point / statement from ISO C++ Standard 14.8.3/5th :Overload resolution

Comment: @BE Student: SO is a Q&A site. You are supposed to ask questions, not statements from the C++ standard. Once again, What Is Your Question?

Comment: @jalf -- He's asking for an explanation of what that statement means, with examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is about what the example shows. In sum, these are those conversions

- The function parameter can be a `Base<T>`, while the function argument is a `Derived<T>`. Compare with `ifstream << "hello"` - left side of `operator<<` is deduced in that way.
- The function parameter can be a `const U&`, while the function argument is a `U` (same for volatile).
- The function parameter can be a `const U*` or `const E C::*` while the function argument is a `U*` or `E C::*` respectively (these are the qualification conversions) - same for volatile.

Other conversions cannot be done for a function parameter / argument that participate in deduction. The whole range of conversions can be applied if a function parameter does *not* participate in deduction, but this needs a non-deduced context or a context where there is no argument to be deduced at all, and implementation don't actually agree on it (see [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1184)).

In other words:

```
template<typename T> struct id { typedef T type; };
template<typename T> void f(T, typename id<T>::type);

int main() {
  // deduction acts on void(int*, int*) - deduction does not need
  // to deduce anything and follows [temp.arg.explicit]p4
  f<int*>(0, 0); 

  // deduction acts on void(T, id<T>::type) - second is a non-deduced context,
  // which *will* allow the conversion of int -> int*, since it will not compare
  // the argument with parameter during deduction (since it is non-deduced).
  f((int*)0, 0);
}
```

The second example is vital for [some partial ordering](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=7708#c2) contexts to work.

Comment: U described about conversions right..Can u able to tell that in a program ... (i mean iam asking for a proof) to check whether it is correct or not

Comment: @USER :In the link ..there is some source ..see that also